# window.close in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox

With the latest update from Firefox I am no longer able to close a page with javascript when a customer clicks the close button on the screen. Below is what I have been using in the past and I can't seem to find an alternative solution. Any idea?

```
var response = confirm('The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window.\n\nDo you want to close the window?');

    if (response) {
        window.open('', '_self');
        window.close();
    }
```

Comment: <rant> BECAUSE IT WAS A HACK TO GET AROUND A SECURITY FEATURE</rant>

Comment: In other words, you were successfully circumventing a security feature (preventing a window from closing unless there was definite proof the user requested that operation) *until now*. Time to go back to the drawing board. Remember that trying to circumvent your browser's security features is an arms race that you can only hope to win temporarily. In the long run, you *will* lose.

Comment: Frédéric Hamidi and  epascarello  you need to calm down. I am not trying deceive anyone. I have a button in the web page that says "CLOSE" and the javascript code would be user initiated by the user.

Comment: @egjoni, oh, I'm not angry (note the lack of caps in my comment), I was just trying to clarify what epascarello was saying. But tell us, why do you want to implement a Close button in your page instead of letting your users close the window the "standard" way (e.g. by clicking the browser-provided Close button in the window caption or tab)?

Comment: It's simply the client's request. They have a blurb and at the bottom they have two buttons, "Continue" or "Discontinue". I am with you when it comes to this and I would rather let the user just hit the 'x' but it's outta my hands. If there is any other way to close it through my button I definitely would entertain it as well.